# Why such a short run time?

Tags: asynchronous, async-await, task, nunit-3.0

I implemented a solution to the dining philosophers problem in C# (some time ago, can't remember when, can't remember where) and I recently reopened it and added some timing output. The test appears to run for only a few milliseconds when the actual test run takes many, many seconds. In fact, I can force it to run for minutes, though the test still shows less than 500 milliseconds.

In short, I'm creating a collection of Tasks, having them run (on and off) for a few seconds each, looping in the main execution until they complete and writing out the difference between the start and end time.

Here is the NUnit unit test being used to run the solution:

```
[Test]
public void DoesEveryOneEat_WaitsForAllToFinish()
{
    // arrange
    var start = DateTime.Now;

    // act
    foreach (var philosopher in Thinkers)
    {
        philosopher.StartEating();
    }

    // wait
    bool someoneIsHungry = true;

    while (someoneIsHungry)
    {
        someoneIsHungry = false;

        foreach (var philosopher in Thinkers)
        {
            if (!someoneIsHungry && philosopher.IsHungry)
                someoneIsHungry = true;
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.Subtract(start).Milliseconds);

    // assert
    Assert.AreEqual(false, Thinkers[0].IsHungry, "Philosopher 0 is hungry and ate for only " + Thinkers[0].AteForMillis + " milliseconds.");
    Assert.AreEqual(false, Thinkers[1].IsHungry, "Philosopher 1 is hungry and ate for only " + Thinkers[1].AteForMillis + " milliseconds.");
    Assert.AreEqual(false, Thinkers[2].IsHungry, "Philosopher 2 is hungry and ate for only " + Thinkers[2].AteForMillis + " milliseconds.");
    Assert.AreEqual(false, Thinkers[3].IsHungry, "Philosopher 3 is hungry and ate for only " + Thinkers[3].AteForMillis + " milliseconds.");
    Assert.AreEqual(false, Thinkers[4].IsHungry, "Philosopher 4 is hungry and ate for only " + Thinkers[4].AteForMillis + " milliseconds.");
}
```

`philosopher.StartEating();` starts a task which runs until a satisfactory outcome has arrived and then exits:

```
public async void StartEating()
{
    await Task.Factory.StartNew(Run);
}

public void Run()
{
    while (_totalRunTime < MaxEatMillis)
    {
        if (Monitor.TryEnter(Left))
        {
            if (Monitor.TryEnter(Right))
            {
                Eat();
                Monitor.Exit(Right);
            }
            Monitor.Exit(Left);
        }
    }
}
```

While I would welcome constructive comments on this code, my question is: Why does the unit test console output only `582` milliseconds when the test itself does not complete for easily `9` seconds or more?

(I would surmise that this is because the time taken for the actual unit test code to run is only 582 milliseconds but that the NUnit library is not allowing the assertions to run until all tasks started by the test to complete. However, this does not vibe in my head properly, as if writing code which would rely on that fact would fail.)

Full listing:

```
public class ChopStick
{
    public int Index { get; set; }
}

public class Philosopher
{
    protected ChopStick Left { get; set; }
    protected ChopStick Right { get; set; }

    private int _totalRunTime = 0;
    private readonly int MaxEatMillis = 3000;
    private readonly int MaxRunMillis = 1000;

    public Philosopher(ChopStick left, ChopStick right)
    {
        Left = left;
        Right = right;
    }

    public async void StartEating()
    {
        await Task.Factory.StartNew(Run);
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        while (_totalRunTime < MaxEatMillis)
        {
            if (Monitor.TryEnter(Left))
            {
                if (Monitor.TryEnter(Right))
                {
                    Eat();
                    Monitor.Exit(Right);
                }
                Monitor.Exit(Left);
            }
        }
    }

    private void Eat()
    {
        var eatTime = new Random().Next(1, MaxRunMillis);
        Thread.Sleep(eatTime);
        _totalRunTime += eatTime;
    }

    public bool IsHungry => _totalRunTime < MaxEatMillis;

    public int AteForMillis => _totalRunTime;
}

[Test]
public void DoesEveryOneEat_WaitsForAllToFinish()
{
    // arrange
    var start = DateTime.Now;

    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.Subtract(start).Milliseconds);

    // act
    foreach (var philosopher in Thinkers)
    {
        philosopher.StartEating();
    }

    // wait
    bool someoneIsHungry = true;

    while (someoneIsHungry)
    {
        someoneIsHungry = false;

        foreach (var philosopher in Thinkers)
        {
            if (!someoneIsHungry && philosopher.IsHungry)
                someoneIsHungry = true;
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.Subtract(start).Milliseconds);

    // assert
    Assert.AreEqual(false, Thinkers[0].IsHungry, "Philosopher 0 is hungry and ate for only " + Thinkers[0].AteForMillis + " milliseconds.");
    Assert.AreEqual(false, Thinkers[1].IsHungry, "Philosopher 1 is hungry and ate for only " + Thinkers[1].AteForMillis + " milliseconds.");
    Assert.AreEqual(false, Thinkers[2].IsHungry, "Philosopher 2 is hungry and ate for only " + Thinkers[2].AteForMillis + " milliseconds.");
    Assert.AreEqual(false, Thinkers[3].IsHungry, "Philosopher 3 is hungry and ate for only " + Thinkers[3].AteForMillis + " milliseconds.");
    Assert.AreEqual(false, Thinkers[4].IsHungry, "Philosopher 4 is hungry and ate for only " + Thinkers[4].AteForMillis + " milliseconds.");

    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.Subtract(start).Milliseconds);
}
```

Comment: I don't see anything here that would cause early exit. But you don't show the code that actually sets `IsHungry`.

Comment: I was trying to avoid posting the entire listing, but I can if that would help.

Comment: So you're saying that the test *does* run for seconds/minutes, but that the test *output* just says it ran for less?

Comment: Yes, that's it exactly.

Comment: I have just updated the post to show where I am writing the times in millis as collected by the unit test. In my latest test run the unit test sessions output showed '0' for about 9 seconds, then two following lines show, in quick succession, '532' and '540' respectively.

Comment: Where do you await for StartEating to finish?

Comment: await Task.Factory.StartNew(Run);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your timing code, you should use `TotalMilliseconds` rather than `Milliseconds`.

Or just output the `TimeSpan` directly:

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.Subtract(start));
```

As a side note, `Stopwatch` is generally used for timings rather than `DateTime.Now`.